# How to style multiple select option in safari (other than color)

Tags: html, css, select, safari

first question here.

I was trying to style forms and I was able to put some padding for multiple select options on chrome but it seems it is not working on safari

It seems we can only change color or background color on safari

Any way around this for more vertical space? (using css)

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<style>
select[multiple] option {
  padding: 20px;
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. You can add padding to the `<select>` element itself, but things go sideways when trying to add padding to the individual `<option>` elements.

[image: Safari Option Styling Limitations]

Styling `<option>` elements cross-platform is *notoriously* difficult.

You might want to look into building a **custom select widget** instead to bypass the cross-platform variance.

Here's a [detailed tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_build_custom_form_widgets) that might help.

---

## Reference

[MDN's compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Property_compatibility_table_for_form_widgets) to at least help you parse through the noise of what's supported. [image: multiline Select box property support table]

They have an [Advanced Styling Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms) as well, however, it's self-admitted that `<select>` forms are indeed a nightmare cross-platform.

[image: Option element styling limitations]